# Getting Foreign Key Values with Linq-to-Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

Hello how can  Getting Foreign Key Values with Linq-to-Entities

```
List<tbl_Modules> List = new List<tbl_Modules>();
var module = from m in OmidPaymakEntity.tbl_ModuleInSubSystem
             where m.Foreign Key== SubSystemID
             select m;
```

Comment: Sorry - what is your question?!?!??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linq to Entities 4 with an EDMX then you have to specify that you want the foreign keys to be mapped, this is done on the update from database dialog.
If you are using a version before 4 then you need to need to go into `ObjectNameReference` property and get the key from that.